# Web-based, free application that helps to manage IP subnets?

Tags: gratis, web-apps, networking, information-management

I need to manage my subnets, see how much free space I have in particular subnets, maybe aggregation or division advises and so on.

UPD.

Well I need something like ManageEngine OpsUtill for free.
One of my teammates installed racktables, and I think it is not good enaugh for subnet housekeeping needs. Imagine a situation when a new guy joins a team, I want to have a tool to point on for the first week for him to discover our environment.

I need.

To see what subnets do we have.

I need to have a magic button, that will show only used IPs from the subnet.

When I add some sever to my environment, I want to add a DNS record in my DNS server and automatically see that in the tool(web interface), and add some 
more data like location.

If there is a lightweight tool that does only this things, then it is much better then racktables for me. But I really look for some cool and free analogue of ManageEngine OpsUtill.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Your requirements are a bit vague. How many subnets are you dealing with? Is a plain table sufficient, or do you need graphs? Statistics about how things evolved? Any specifics about the backend? What environment are you planning to host it on? Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you look at  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_mapping